# Finding P.M.F of maximum ordered statistic of discrete uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3....X_n$ be a sample from PMF

$P(X=x)=P_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{N}   \ \ \ \ ;x=1,2,...N$

$X_n=$max($X_1,X_2,X_3....X_n$)

I calculated P.M.F of $X_n$ from this formula $n(F_X(x))^{n-1}f_X(x)$

$F_X(x)=\dfrac{x}{N}$

$f_{X_n}(x)=n\bigg(\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{N^{n}}\bigg)$

But in my textbook it is written as $\dfrac{x^n}{N^n}-\dfrac{(x-1)^{n}}{N^n}$

Where did I do it wrong ?

Comment: Can you define $X_n$ ? Is it the max of $n$ RV distributed as you described and independents ?

Comment: @P.Quinton yes let me define it sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula that you used is derived from differentiating $(F_X(x))^n$, that is it is a formula meant for continuous random variable.

For discrete uniform, we have

\begin{align}
Pr(X_n = x) &= Pr(X_n \le x) - Pr(X_n \le x-1) \\
&= \left(\frac{x}{N} \right)^n - \left(\frac{x-1}{N} \right)^n
\end{align}

Comment: Even for discrete case $F_{X_n}(x)=P(max(X_i)\le x)$

=$P(X_1<x)P(X_2<x)...P(X_n<x)=(F_X(x))^n$

Comment: $f_{X_n}(x)=n(F_X(x))^{n-1}(P(X=x))$

Comment: Do you mean your formula holds for discrete case? is that cited from a book or a note? is a derivation provided?

Comment: Correction $P(X_n=x)=n(F_X(x))^{n-1}(P(X=x))$. Yes, I just tried to prove you for discrete case. isn't it valid? No, I didn't look up any book. My book just states CDF of a max ordered statistic as a heading.

Comment: Perhaps consider Bernoulli and see if your formula works?